# loop to find the parent id until it gives null

Tags: mysql, parent-child

Can anyone help me query. I have the same problem as the picture 1 below. The difference is that my data in picture 2 is different from his. If I search for the user id it will give me the parent id, and then it will search for the parent id in the user id until it gives null. Thank you.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epDIS.jpg)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7aAW.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tested my query and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
   with  cte(col1,col2,col3) as (
      select     col1,
                 col2,
                 col3
      from       sample1 
      where      col1 = 1
      union all
      select     yt.col1,
                 yt.col2,
                 yt.col3
      from       sample1 yt
      inner join cte 
      On yt.col1 = cte.col3
    )
    select * from cte
```

You will see result for col1=1

[image]

I added this field to show stored procedure example.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Recrusive(col VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
 with  cte(col1,col2,col3) as (
      select     col1,
                 col2,
                 col3
      from       sample1 
      where      col1 = col
      union all
      select     yt.col1,
                 yt.col2,
                 yt.col3
      from       sample1 yt
      inner join cte 
      On yt.col1 = cte.col3
    )
    select * from cte

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You are welcome. It is recrusive code. I always try to find simpliest and use less code.

Comment: can we use the value of this generated query as a variable for the same query? the image is in my question bro.thank you very much

Comment: For example you can write a stored procedure with one parameter and when you need you can call this procedure with one parameter. I think we can write with one more recursive cte. Maybe at this time we may not need parameter.

Comment: could you please explain more about the code?thank you

Comment: which ones will you use? Sql or mysql

Comment: my sql @yusuf hayirserver

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that the depth is not fixed (it might vary), I don't see another way to do it rather that using a stored procedure/function with a loop.
Below is a working example using a `stored procedure`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(IN `number` int)
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE parentNumber INT DEFAULT NULL;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
    
    SET parentNumber = number;
    
    myloop: 
    WHILE (parentNumber IS NOT NULL)
    DO 
    
        SET @cnt = 0;
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @cnt FROM test WHERE col1 = parentNumber;
        
        IF @cnt = 1 THEN
            INSERT INTO temp1 SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = parentNumber;
            SELECT col3 INTO parentNumber FROM test WHERE col1 = parentNumber;
        ELSE
            LEAVE myloop;
        END IF;
            
        IF parentNumber IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE myloop;
        END IF;
         
    END WHILE myloop;
    
    SELECT * FROM temp1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;

END
```

You can alter it according to your needs, but must importantly: try to understand and play with it, not just plug-it-in and go.

Comment: could you help me identify the variables that im going to insert to that code that you give cause im having trouble what input will i put .

Comment: @olankendrick you only pass the value you want, as a parameter. `Call test(1)` (parameter `number`). Now, this parameter is `INT`, but your values might be `varchar`, so if you want you can alter the procedure and make `number` and `parentnumber` as `varchar` for example.